# Spring Boot - Jackson unable to POST / PUT when using list fields (@ManyToMany)

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-boot, jackson

**Explanation**

I made a sample code to test http methods, to my surprise I found a problem when trying to convert the JSON to an object on list fields, it crashed, but as soon as I remove that field everything works fine.

---

**Sample structure** *(skipped fields such as the **id** for this example)*

```
{
    "name": "One",
    "child": {
        "name": "Two",
        "nested": [
            {
                "name": "Three"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

---

**Expected**

Being able to **POST** and **PUT**, error is thrown at the moment.

**Actual**

I get an error, but as soon as I delete that **Nested** field everything works fine, also **GET** and **DELETE** are work fine even with the **Nested** field in there.

**Error thrown**

Failed to evaluate Jackson deserialization for type [[simple type, class **com.base.project.Parent**]]: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Cannot handle managed/back reference 'defaultReference': back reference type (**java.util.List**) not compatible with managed type (**com.base.project.Child**)

---

*I'm going to skip some fields so this doesn't become a cluster*

---

**class Parent** *(the top layer, has the name **One** in the structure shown at the top)*

```
@JsonManagedReference // I already tried removing this
@OneToOne(mappedBy = "parent", cascade {...})
private Child child;
```

**class Child** *(the middle layer, has the name **Two** in the structure shown at the top)*

```
@JsonBackReference
@OneToOne(cascade = {...})
@JoinColumn(name = "parent_id")
private Parent parent;

@JsonManagedReference // I already tried removing this
@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "child", cascade = {...})
private List<Nested> nested;
```

**class Nested** *(the bottom layer, has the name **Three** in the structure shown at the top)*

```
@JsonBackReference
@ManyToMany(cascade = {...})
@JoinTable(...)
private List<Child> child;
```

---

**Things I tried**

- Removing @JsonManagedReference
- Added @JsonIdentityInfo to the three classes
- Using @JsonProperty on the relational fields
- Removing the **Nested** field (@ManyToMany), just then it works fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Original problem as described**

The solution was to remove any `@JsonManagedReference` besides the one from the top layer, so in my example **Parent** is the only one who has that annotation, the other two (**Child** and **Nested** are just using `@JsonBackReference`)

Note, I'm aware that pretty much the **Child** class is a "parent" to the **Nested** class, however, adding `@JsonManagedReference` to it was throwing an error, so again, the top layer is the only one who needs it, for some reason.

This only fixed the **POST** method.

---

**Second problem, the PUT method wasn't detecting the id from any of the childs**

Providing the **id** in the JSON body was throwing an error, however upon removing the **id** field it was all right (*although for obvious reasons I couldn't update them on the database*)

I had set the following at the top of my three classes

```
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property = "id")
```

(*id is the name of the field in my class which stores... the id*)

**Don't** quote me on this, but I believe having that annotation along `@JsonManagedReference` and `@JsonBackReference` was causing some sort of problem in the **PUT** method, the **POST** wasn't affected whatsoever.

Needless to say, as soon as I removed `@JsonIdentityInfo` while leaving the other two fixed the problem.

This fixed the **PUT** method.